# How do i know which associations are available in a shopware 6 store api endpoint

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm using the Shopware 6 `store-api` for my headless application.
But i cannot figure out which associations are available in the Shopware `store-api`
for example:

1. I call `store-api/account/customer` but also want for example the last order.
2. I call `store-api/login` and i also want the customer details (like name, email etc).
3. I call `store-api/seo-urls`. And if the `routeName` is `frontend.detail.page` i want to get the product details

Is this possible in one api-call? Or do i need to make another request with response data?
And how can i check this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Store-API it depends if the endpoint allows you to provide a `Criteria` that lets you include additional `associations`. See the corresponding request body in documentation for example [in the Shopware Docs](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b3A6ODI2NTY0Ng-get-information-about-current-customer).

To find which associations are available per entity you could look at the code in the respective extensions of `EntityDefinition`, e.g. the [`ProductDefintion`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b82e602998d163a68c560bec89af0dd59b1b6278/src/Core/Content/Product/ProductDefinition.php).